# ASP.Net UpdateProgress breaks when scripts are added to ScriptManager

Tags: javascript, asp.net, mootools, scriptmanager, updateprogress

I'm having trouble with the UpdateProgress and the ScriptManager in ASP.Net. The UpdateProgress fails to display (Inline CSS property | display:none;) when a script is registered in the ScriptManager. I have also registered the script programmatically under the page load method using this method, [ASP.NET 4.5 ScriptManager Improvements in WebForms](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/09/21/asp-net-4-5-scriptmanager-improvements-in-webforms.aspx), but still fails. Thanks in advance :).

Aspx:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server">            
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/mootools-core-1.4.5.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/mootools-more-1.4.0.1.js" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" /> 
                        <div id="panel2Div" runat="server"></div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
                    <ProgressTemplate>
                        <p>Doing Stuff....</p>
                    </ProgressTemplate>
                </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            panel2Div.InnerHtml = "Updated Panel 2";
        }
```

if the Script/ScriptReference tags are removed in the ScriptManager, the UpdateProgress  works!

**EDIT** - Problem solved thanks to the pointer given by Nathan. There is indeed a conflict between Mootools and MS AJAX. This is because of the declaration "Type" in Mootools core/more, which is overridden by the MS AJAX. Luckily, it can be adverted 
by changing the declaration from "Type" to something else. I found the solution [*HERE*](https://mootools.lighthouseapp.com/projects/2706/tickets/1045-asp-net-bug), under 'Scott's' post, great name BTW ;).

*The steps I took were:*

1. Open up your Mootools core and more files (I used VS2012, but
   Notepad++ should work fine)
2. Find (CTRL+F) "new Type" and replace with "new mooTools"
3. Find (CTRL+F) "this.Type" and replace with "this.mooTools"
4. Find (CTRL+F) "Type" and replace with "mooTools"
5. Make sure that you do this for both files (unless your only using core)

Big thanks to Nathan and 'Scott' for helping me out.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tested this in all browsers (IE,Chrome,FF,Nightly) and works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably has something to do with the mootools not playing nicely with asp.net ajax.  This article might help you out:  [asp.net forums on mootools not working with asp.net ajax](http://forums.asp.net/t/1340217.aspx)